# Firebase SDK on multiple pages interrupts database ref

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications, sdk

I am using Firebase to host my site and a Real-time Database for a form inside it, but my code only works when I paste my full SDK into the HTML, despite my wishes to insert it with a vanilla JavaScript function.

For example, my JavaScript function with the SDK is:

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    var clfb = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    {//scripts
        clfb.innerHTML +=
            '<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-app.js"></script>'
        +
            '<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>'
        +
            '<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-database.js"></script>'
        +
            '<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>'
        +
            '<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>'        
    }
    {//config
        clfb.innerHTML +=
        '<script>' + 
            'var firebaseConfig = {\
                apiKey: "??",\
                authDomain: "??-fb.firebaseapp.com",\
                databaseURL: "https://??-fb.firebaseio.com",\
                projectId: "??-fb",\
                storageBucket: "??.appspot.com",\
                messagingSenderId: "??",\
                appId: "??",\
                measurementId: "G-??"\
                }'
         + '</script>'
    }
    {//init
        clfb.innerHTML +=
            '<script>' +
                'firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);'
            +
                'firebase.analytics();'
            +
            '</script>'
    }
}
```

And my form to database Js code is:

```
const submittedWords = firebase.database().ref('add_words');

function submitWords(){
    const word = document.getElementById('word').value;
    const lang = document.getElementById('lang').value;
    saveWords(word, lang);
    alert('word has been sent');
    function saveWords(word, lang) {
        const newMessageRef = submittedWords.push();
        newMessageRef.set({
            word: word,
            lang: lang,
        });
    }
}
```

The `const submittedWords = firebase.database().ref('add_words');` is outside the functions because it did not work when I declared it inside one; I have also tried to add the SDK outside any `function(){}`, or as a single `innerHTML` line, or as a `prepend` or an `appendChild`, and also inside the `body` element with `createElement`. The code was inserted in all methods mentioned, but the database firebase function did not.

Comment: Can I ask why you're inserting the script tags with innerHTML instead of just simply declaring them in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: I have tried that too, but got a lot of 'firebase is not defined' errors.

Comment: I suggest you start from this article my friend. Modern web applications are just not built with raw, handcoded HTML anymore: https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial